# Why does the captcha image src not lead to an image?

Tags: python, selenium, captcha

So I have this captcha that I am trying to solve but the image src doesn't go to an image, but this is what i get:

```
�PNG  IHDR�K��|^iPLTE���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������fff���:j pHYs���+�IDATh���Y�븲C#�����v���(t���Sg�Wڐ� �!��0��k͟�Z���%�� !B̙�fW��I��nZ5��\��=�94{?�:Z9��&G$j,�~�7$"iiUm'��1�0M����p��� ��� H��ْ���N?��ǥw/j�fT1�2EU��΋���Mp(b��)���<�����C��l�)��Dؒ�D10�}�����Yk�m�a�j\��*��|n�F���-qY�Q�^���(y ՜Тxm�ܪp���[,ړCT!�bBVe�4�QA��K��b}P��ӿ� �w;�)Y�o�.L�U܅����++%�64�>3�ޛ\)z�ii�߰Ӥ�� ��׏N������'�F�&ǂ�ħ�`gMg6k'&h�d����Е?uX��������Y�(^WC�^+��RO�f]T�� ~��U׋wR���/��Oa�P�����ꭶ��`[�1�^�xV��Rdão���[cQ�M��w酐�)�/�� �L��C�e٢����dK��Qe☷�۪y�]^�C�*�];����f�"+��`ږ��0h�*�F�N%&�J���{�5��$Vs9���43��ObV��'o��U�Kh׷.�wJ �ay$~EQ-lyQ�� ��֙�8��M�ٚ �5F�2�ʢ�g����%Y�P�����FfS��Hn=�ͨ�g�BE\�������.�̹�v�5}ٯ�{�]F5N+F���}Cyy:-/6!��1� �hi��3,��>�� _ơc �f���}\X_G|c�&U��#V0��q�a��Vt����Oj���  ���h���E:z��/&o?N3�/Ny-]Q|[�6�we������'7/���l�;6Z�/�q�~����A1*��i̭ul�Y������hn?��J����#b���9팺� `R�(j���R�j�r^iį4(ٚd-v'v��q�8��2Ҩfx��\R�f�ɰ�m�޿���؉A���de���x]R�7��RLv ��C��6�eلG���b�!.��n����ݙi}������S����KJ� ���,{�&9�h<��/����&���1�� � ��B���p;�c*�S*j��X����3A��yĽDk���+#qX�� ����jS;[2^�::Î �zJ�t�e�I�Z�g�M�H�ˮk*�D�/r�^����7�-<�hY'_��S�k�%�����)�2#-%�.-�a�d��.������=i��vd��Rˑ�Θˎ�Ek�Q�^�߱0�bx�����y�EЁ�e�.��<6�٢<�U��B��!���`���=1KVEٚ�0�����a�.�I��'�)� ��>���R�XK�Jy�uϥ��i��TN?�hЮ�8:HLC�)LE�����|�=�D��q��6���9������7nC$�^���zP�=�PAť_o4h'�4 ��`KK%��?_J�������N�M�/�����P�D�ј#����eT0�袞_0�o4�����ӹ:_�����Xd�4����wN4mg Ol.�&"ia��6k�qq��ae����Mo4h���U�,����͢e��3��Yk`�}�q-��{e�����定�������E@bI�)�l��4�oXpQ�Ih����=�˄9՞ÉAZ�d����`�Y�����[��%���l�g����a�����@�/�_(=%�0���(�M6�A%̠�����Wv�ꭀ�/��(�<:�e܃�������F6�c��1�K�w[o�HU̍��S'LP�CƖ�R����e�vy�Cۑ}�<6��ty�a7y�kq��h�/1�l¸����?N ӄ��ׇdXkx(L9t��;�w@ȩ�T⑮s�+t&��J�������J�ΐ1�V��v� �K�ƐQr7�_6A:����A��*F]݋�|D>��'t#��B��3�=��F���������PWD��tfVv�`5��FjG����N��� ;� ���Կ�#x���#�+�sC78�7I�L���-W��-́��6U�f�q����7��by�-I��]��v����z�Ӗ�<�h����q���-�=�{�A(�S?c�}E��������Qdu�%���%%�&4��'����9;�M%�FO�2�b�C��TY��Ö����Wll��y�,|�����c�j�.6Ɣ�����ȭ�� t�^p�B�ʴt�=��ѷ����V]Dk��n�o6���g9�`R�q��U���EYv#S�����n�Y�h�ܛ�"�m�� ��Uű����|P���ε�K��> l�'��T��3��ab':�Zg���>����<�&�o4�>_��샷дd_�*�6�ˊH:�0���� 8�<6g�4����[Į�[�&�}�=�&�+ ؃܊AE�����`�#�bF嘞�`z��)�ةݤL�Wp��5�:��6^Ӑ�կ�7#�;�!���s��ľm��תHَ�7 J�.��FY�%[Ot�d�����8�T�����m�������cT˻RE0Z�n����[���9T[7�V� ���Ԩ߾��<ʳ�B|M��8GgmS����<���rz�6J�XE& ��cņ����l?M���F�h����@�2����ѺME�l>ww�Od�1�Q��-]ZK����6$槊���M�����~�A &�ם����������[' ������F�X嶏IJFI0K�\e'ؔNg�,���������kC���(�K��e�i�7�@d��#�1�V�N>� g��h��E<�H-�����M%A�ϐ�)���2���H� �A�8qM��M ��R�YDCPI�մ�~�ƍ�&�j��q=������&�W����t��V�J��m�V���]^w�P}H����%�`&��jV 9����GM�tRUSc��V��H��·�������h��e�Nj��_�k��1� ^z!Ű?t�����]�o�d���r_�l {r�/�A�CI}�"\�;�c��渲R�-�#���5~8D����7X���f�s�Y�s�`w>Y!�qӲ�E�(�+�}�Ƨ��,Z��3�bpa �f���-9�'�9�� @g[��.ױܣ�|�I����d�2��{+�~�fE5B�`^� %l�I����+�=B V�f��7��2��6�|P�_��y���r�j�h�m�?�Q�0��\�m+����/ z�L�0�^��������<�N�� �c�\O5yy*e�"w�:�R��pШ1gg���إ��%����6�4�����8+����{L5�h���>��u�J���(��g80��|��K�(�<@zG�a����~Vwr����ڔ�RGJ�]dVWo4���K9
```

Is there a way I can get the actual image or somehow decode this into an image?

I'm using selenium python

NOTE:

The data changes every time I reload the page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That IS the image, or at least, the bytes that make up the image as interpreted by printable and non-printable characters. Use an image library like `PIL` to instantiate an image object using these bytes.

Comment: Well what is the name of this encoding. I know how to decode base64, so is this simillar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can be told by HTML to display images in 2 ways:

- `here's a URL, fetch it and show it here`, or
- `here's some binary data, reassemble and show it here`

This is an instance of the latter.

The data can be in one of 2 (or possibly more) formats, which will influence how you preprocess before saving:

- base64 encoded: decode then save
- binary encoded: save directly

Good news is there's usually breadcrumbs (so the browser doesn't have to guess either): `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...`